# Core Data Design

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to extend my generated `NSManagedObject` classes (data mapping, init, utility functions).  I was doing this with categories, but doing two imports got old real fast.  I saw that MagicalRecord subclassed the generated files (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/develop/Samples/iOS/Application/Models).  I tried this approach, but ran into the following problem.

`[foo.bar myExtensionMethod];`

Where foo is of class `_foo` and bar is of class `_bar`.  The method `myExtensionMethod` is in the subclass of `_bar` named `bar`.  I get a syntax error along the lines of `_bar` does not have function `myExtensionMethod`.

#### question

Is there a way to extend generated `NSManagedObject` classes that doesn't require two imports or something like modgenerator?  As I regenerate the files, manually editing the generated files isn't an option.

Comment: mogenerator doesn't require two imports. You only import the non underscore class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes with underscore (`_Foo`, `_Bar`) are overwritten by mogenerator with the
current properties of your Core Data entities, and you should not modify these.

Your extension methods should go into the classes without underscore (`Foo`, `Bar`),
and you need only include "Foo.h" or "Bar.h".

Comment: I'm not using modgenerator nor do I want to.  `_Foo` has a relationship with `_Bar`, so `foo.bar` is referencing the `_Bar` class not `Bar` (where the `myExtensionMethod` is).

Comment: @JeffCompton: Then I misunderstood your question. (The MagicalRecord sample project *uses* mogenerator to create _Ingredient.*, _Recipe.*.)

Comment: Well, balls.  Looks like I'm going that route.  Thanks.